# INNER JOIN with MAX Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Help I'm new to programming I need to get the highest version data of each EXE names. I found same articles about this, but we have different table structures so they didn't really help me on my problem.
I have this tables:

> table mForm

```
FormID     FormName         EXEname       CurrentVersion 
--------------------------------------------------------
BTC-01      CASH REVIEW     BTC-01.EXE    1.0.2.5
BTC-02      CASH REQUEST    BTC-02.EXE    1.1.2.4
BTC-03      PAYMENTS        BTC-03.EXE    1.0.0.3
```

> table mVersionHistory

```
EXEname         FormName        Version      ReleasedDate  ReleaseDescription
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
BTC-01.EXE      CASH REVIEW     1.0.2.5      08-08-16      IT REQ 10063
BTC-01.EXE      CASH REVIEW     1.0.2.4      08-08-10      IT REQ 10051 
BTC-01.EXE      CASH REVIEW     1.0.2.3      08-08-09      IT REQ 10050
BTC-02.EXE      CASH REQUEST    1.1.2.4      08-08-13      IT REQ 10003
BTC-02.EXE      CASH REQUEST    1.1.2.0      08-08-10      IT REQ 10002 
BTC-03.EXE      PAYMENTS        1.0.0.2      08-08-07      IT REQ 10102
BTC-03.EXE      PAYMENTS        1.0.0.1      08-08-06      IT REQ 10092
```

> I want to return distinct data with the highest Versions.
>   like this:

```
EXEname         FormName        CurrentVersion   Version      ReleasedDate  ReleaseDescription
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BTC-01.EXE      CASH REVIEW     1.0.2.5          1.0.2.5      08-08-16      IT REQ 10063
BTC-02.EXE      CASH REQUEST    1.1.2.4          1.1.2.4      08-08-13      IT REQ 10003
BTC-03.EXE      PAYMENTS        1.0.0.3          1.0.0.2      08-08-07      IT REQ 10102
```

I can do it with my code but the problem is, I cant add the Description and ReleaseDate columns, every time I add them, all data would show up since they have different data in Description and ReleaseDate Columns.

```
SELECT 
A.FormID [FORM ID]
, A.FormName [FORM NAME]
, A.ExeName [EXE NAME]
, A.CurrentVersion [CURRENT VERSION]
, B.RVersion AS [RELEASED VERSION]
FROM 
mForm A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Exename, MAX(Version) AS RVersion
FROM mVersionHistory
GROUP BY ExeName) B
ON A.ExeName = B.ExeName
GROUP BY A.FormID, B.FormName, A.CurrentVersion, B.RVersion, A.ExeName
```

Where should I add the Description and ReleaseDate columns?
Thanks

Comment: table mForm is already have latest version of each application, right?

Comment: @qxg yeah they have the latest versions

Comment: Then I didn't get why you `MAX` version again.

Comment: @qxg It's a monitoring query, the mForm table contains the latest versions of EXE Files, the mVersionHistory table contains the released versions. I need to monitor if the latest versions were already released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT A.formid                   [FORM ID], 
                A.formname                 [FORM NAME], 
                A.exename                  [EXE NAME], 
                A.currentversion           [CURRENT VERSION], 
                B.rversion                 AS [RELEASED VERSION], 
                ---You can add whatever columns need from mversionhistory table
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY A.exename ORDER BY b.version DESC) AS Rn 
         FROM   mform A 
                INNER JOIN mversionhistory B 
                        ON A.exename = B.exename) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross apply in later SQL versions

```
SELECT 
A.FormID [FORM ID]
, A.FormName [FORM NAME]
, A.ExeName [EXE NAME]
, A.CurrentVersion [CURRENT VERSION]
, c.RVersion AS [RELEASED VERSION]
FROM 
mForm A
cross apply
(SELECT top 1 Exename, Version AS RVersion
FROM mVersionHistory B
 where  A.ExeName = B.ExeName and a.FormName = b.FormName
order by version desc) c
```

Comment: I will go for this approach if I have proper Index